# NDepend rule for "Dispose objects before losing scope"

Tags: ndepend, ca2000, cqlinq

I'm evaluating NDepend as a part of an effort to enforce code quality and correct framework usage, and I am looking for a way to write the equivalent of [CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx). Anyone else has tried to do this, or has knowledge about how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This rule is not implementable through NDepend because the context is inside method body. NDepend is more about writing [code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) concerning the program structure like for example:

- [Types with disposable instance fields must be disposable](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_with_disposable_instance_fields_must_be_disposable.html)
- [Disposable types with unmanaged resources should declare finalizer](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Disposable_types_with_unmanaged_resources_should_declare_finalizer.html)